# JAX-WS webservice on tomcat - cannot be instantiated

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat

I would like to know how to handle this situation.
what i have done is i have followed the tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/deploy-jax-ws-web-services-on-tomcat-ssl-connection/ 
to create a  similar secured web service, i am able to achieve it, but i have a error ,

ml.ws.api.server.InstanceResolver.createNewInstance(InstanceResolver.java:222)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.InstanceResolver.createDefault(InstanceResolver.java:184)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.create(EndpointFactory.java:209)

the error is because i am instantiating the webservice for example from this example the HelloWorldImpl class has a constructor with arguments to set a parameter from a class.
I understand , only default constructor is possible in Jax-ws web service, but in that case i want to know how to handle this?

say like

```
package com.mkyong.ws;

import javax.jws.WebService;

//Service Implementation Bean

@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.mkyong.ws.HelloWorld")
public class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloWorld{
private ABC abc;
 public HelloWorldImpl (ABC abc)
{
    this.abc = abc;
}
    @Override
    public String getHelloWorldAsString() {
        return "Hello World JAX-WS";
    }

// and i use this abc in one of the methods 
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what is going to be invoking this Constructor, and how would you provide it the abc instance?

Answer (score 1):

This is not the correct notation for a constructor:

```
public void HelloWorldImpl (ABC abc) {
    this.abc = abc;
}
```

Should be:

```
public HelloWorldImpl (ABC abc) {
    this.abc = abc;
}
```

Update: So why not add a default constructor?

```
package com.mkyong.ws;

import javax.jws.WebService;

//Service Implementation Bean

@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.mkyong.ws.HelloWorld")
public class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloWorld {
private ABC abc;

public HelloWorldImpl() { 
    this("Hello World JAX-WS");
}

 public HelloWorldImpl (ABC abc)
{
    this.abc = abc;
}
    @Override
    public String getHelloWorldAsString() {
        return this.getAbc();
    }

// and i use this abc in one of the methods 
}
```

Comment: but the question remains the same , can anyone please answer it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can control how the HelloWorldImpl gets created by using: `@InstanceResolverAnnotation`

I wasn't able to find any good example, but here is one link that uses this annotation: http://blog.vinodsingh.com/2008/12/let-spring-load-service-class-for-jax.html

The idea is that the class specified as the Value for this Annotation, will be used to create the Instance of HelloWorld WebService.

Comment: ,Thank you, but i dont use Spring, I solved it by not instantiating but by gettters and setters though not a preferred one it works in my case.

Comment: That annotation is a jax-ws annotation.  Any WebService implementation (Spring-WS or otherwise) should be able to support it. In my opinion, this annotation is the preferred way address your original question.

Comment: But, I do agree, that in most cases, solving things by getters and setters (vs constructor) is a better idea.